# Arduino Array Scope with SPI

Tags: arduino-mega, spi

when I try the following code the SPI works correctly (see oscilloscope plot)

```
#include <SPI.h>

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(100000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  byte a[] = {0xC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
  SPI.transfer(a, 4);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  delay(10);
}
```

[image]

However when I move the array declaration to the a global it doesn't work any more. (see next oscilloscope plot) Why is this?

```
#include <SPI.h>

byte a[] = {0xC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(100000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  SPI.transfer(a, 4);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  delay(10);
}
```

[image]

Comment: it is not necessarily anything related to SPI ... use `byte a[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};` and do `serial.write(a[0])` to print a value to serial monitor ... see if the result is the same

Comment: From the code you show I don't see any problem. It should work. Hm...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `SPI.transfer(a, 4);`, any "received data" is stored in your byte array, `a[]`. The original data is overwritten.

If you print out the contents of the array before and after the function call to `SPI.transfer()`, you will see in the serial monitor what is happening to your array contents.

Here are 2 test sketches to illustrate the difference between the array with a global scope, VS the one with a static scope.

**Global Scope**

```cpp
// Sketch uses 2344 bytes (7%) of program storage space.
// Global variables use 193 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory. 
#include <SPI.h>

byte a[] = {0xC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(100000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
  SPI.transfer(a, 4);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println('\n');
  delay(1000);
}
```

**Static Scope**

```cpp
// Sketch uses 2410 bytes (7%) of program storage space.
// Global variables use 193 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory. 
#include <SPI.h>

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(100000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  byte a[] = {0xC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
  SPI.transfer(a, 4);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println('\n');
  delay(1000);
}
```

The following sketch should solve the problem. Using the `const` keword before the declaration of the `b[]` array is optional.

```cpp
// Sketch uses 2436 bytes (7%) of program storage space.
// Global variables use 197 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory. 
#include <SPI.h>
const byte b[] = {0xC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(100000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  byte a[] = {0xC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
  SPI.transfer(a, 4);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  memcpy(a, b, sizeof(b));
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println('\n');
  delay(1000);
}
```

One last edit. The compile size can be reduced by 66 bytes thanks to the `static` keyword.

```cpp
// Sketch uses 2370 bytes (7%) of program storage space.
// Global variables use 197 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory. 
#include <SPI.h>
const byte b[] = {0xC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(100000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  static byte a[] = {0xC,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
  SPI.transfer(a, 4);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  memcpy(a, b, sizeof(b));
  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
  Serial.println('\n');
  delay(1000);
}
```

For more information, see: [Arduino.cc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPITransfer)